# Stack Overflow when calling a function that generates a lazy list?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, lazy-evaluation

I can define an infinite data structure - aka lazy list - like this.

`let 'a lazylist = Succ of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazylist);;`

(Why can't I replace `unit -> 'a lazylist` with `() -> 'a lazylist`?)

The way I understand lazy data structures the above definition says that a lazy list consists of a tupel of a generic element `'a` and a function `unit->'a lazylist` that will compute the next element in the list when called with `()` which is of type unit.

So e.g. I could generate a list that has every even number:

```
let rec even_list l = 
  match l with 
    Succ (a, l') -> 
      if (a mod 2 = 0) then 
        Succ (a, fun() -> even_list (l' ())
      else  
        even_list (l' ());;
```

The way I understand it: When `fun() -> even_list (l'()))` is called with the unit argument `()` it will call `even_list` with the successor of `l'` by giving it `unit` as an argument: `l'()`

But is it possible for the `else even_list (l'());;` part to lead to a Stack Overflow if we give even_list a lazylist as an argument that only consists of uneven elements e.g.? Whereas in the then part of the if-statement we only generate the next element of the list when called with `()` - in the else part we would search indefinitely.

Comment: Note that where you're using a `match` with a single pattern, you can directly pattern match your function's argument.  `let rec even_list (Succ (a, l')) = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can use the built-in `Seq.t` type rather than define your own lazy list type.

Second, your function `even_list` is tail-recursive and cannot result in a stack overflow.

Third, if you are using the `take` function proposed in [Call lazy-list function in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71541147/call-lazy-list-function-in-ocaml), it is this function which is not tail-recursive and consumes stack.

You can write a tail-recursive version of this function

```
let rec take l n (Succ(x,f)) =
  if n = 0 then List.rev l
  else take (x::l) (n-1) (f ())
let take n l = take [] n l
```

or define a `fold` function

```ml
let rec fold_until n f acc (Succ(x,l)) =
  if n = 0 then acc
  else fold_until (n-1) f (f acc x) (l())
```

and use that function to define a printer that does not build an intermediary list.

(This is why it is generally advised to write-down a fully self-contained example, otherwise the issue is too often hidden in the implicit context of the question.)

Comment: Thank you - you are right that the function is tail-recursive. But when I give a lazy list with odd numbers as an argument it wouldn't stop running or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right, `even_list` applied on a infinite list of odd numbers will never return.